# How to add a 0 to end of list of lists using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wanted to add 0 to help in smoothing in ML. I used basic for loop, but since there are huge number of rows greater than 50000, I wanted to know if there is a specific numpy method which does the same job? 
like:

a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
by appending 0,

we get

a = [[1,2,3,0],[4,5,6,0]]

I have already ran the basic python code using for loop. Also I tried using numpy.append which only needs a proper matrix.

I used

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
for x in a:
     x.append(0)
```

I wish to get a = [[1,2,3,0],[4,5,6,0]] using numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.hstack` function, like example bellow:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
np.hstack((a, np.zeros([2, 1])))
```

Answer (score 2):

To put Aliakbar's answer in more explicit form, the answer is the following:

```py
b = np.zeros(row_no)
np.hstack((a, b))
```

will do the trick. Alternative way will be `np.vstack((a,b))` if you want to add new rows, and for more generic purposes, `np.concatenate((a,b), axis=1)` works as well.